# Почему не присваивается значения поля. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Значение поля `min` не присваивается полю `result`. Почему?

```js
$('#ok').click(function() {
  $('#min').val = $('#result').val
});
```

```css
#result {
  background-color: black;
  color: #33FF00;
  width: 85%;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 4px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="min" maxlength="5">min
<input type="text" id="max" maxlength="5">max
<button id="ok">Submit</button>
<br>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

`$().val()` - это функция. При отсутствии аргумента она возвращает текущее значение элемента `input` (`select`, `textarea`), при наличии - устанавливает.

`#result` - это элемент с тагом `p`. У него нет значения, но есть `innerText` или `innerHTML` - соответственно, `$().text` или `$().html()` в терминах jQuery.

```
<input type="text" id="min" maxlength="5">min
<input type="text" id="max" maxlength="5">max
<button id="ok">Submit</button>
<br>
<p id="result">aaa</p>
```

В одну сторону:

```
$('#result').text($('#min').val());
```

в другую:

```
$('#min').val($('#result').text());
```

Comment: text, val, html не работает

Comment: $('#result').text($('#min').val()) - так работает

Comment: в JSfiddle? Ничего не меняю

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что `val()` - метод, а не переменная; порядок присвоения вы перепутали местами; да и содержимое(к примеру, текст) контейнерных элементов устанавливается не через `val()`, а через `text()` либо `html()`.

```js
$('#ok').click(function(){
 var value = $('#min').val();
 $('#result').text(value);
});
```

```css
#result {
  background-color: black;
  color: #33FF00;
  width: 85%;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 4px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="min" maxlength="5">min
<input type="text" id="max" maxlength="5">max
<button id="ok">Submit</button>
<br>
<p id="result"></p>
```